# How to prevent form action when onsubmit confirm return false?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, onsubmit

In my HTML form I want to display a `confirm()` box before the user goes to the next page. I am using jQuery AJAX with an `onsubmit` attribute on the `form`.

The problem is that the AJAX request runs every time, even if I click on the cancel button in the confirm dialog box. How can I stop the AJAX request when the user clicks cancel in the confirm box?

```html
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do You want to Continue?');" action="#" id="renewbyuser" method="POST">
  <input class="renew button dark-gray" type="submit" name="renewnow" value="Renew Now">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#renewbyuser").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      // ajax runs here
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're assigning two individual event handlers, so although you prevent the first based on the result of `confirm()`, the `submit` event you listen to through jQuery still fires.

To fix this, put the `confirm()` call within the `submit` event handler and remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the `form` tag in your HTML:

```html
<form action="#" id="renewbyuser" method="POST">
  <input class="renew button dark-gray" type="submit" name="renewnow" value="Renew Now" />
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#renewbyuser").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!confirm('Do You want to Continue?'))
      return;

    $.ajax({
      // ajax runs here
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is not to use form to submit data to backend. You just need to use ajax to post data and prevent action like that:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <button class="renew button dark-gray" id='btn-submit' name="renewnow" value="Renew Now">    
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-submit").on('click',(e) =>{
    let check =confirm("do u want to continue!");
    if(check){
      $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url: 'formSubmitUrl'
        data : dataForm
      }).done((result)=>{});
    } 
  });
});
```

or use `jqueryForm` library to do you want